# How to undo a change in only a certain part of a picture in Gimp

Tags: image, gimp

I've been cleaning up a picture in Gimp, deleting things in several places.

I later realized that I deleted something that I shouldn't have deleted.

I want to undo this change, but I don't want to lose all the other changes in other areas of the picture.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

edit -> copy
file -> create from clipboard
edit -> undo at will

And then copy/paste from the backup image you created on the step above.